# How do I install things? Or, what's xcb and qt and how do they solve the riddles of my life?

Tags: software-installation, qt, teamspeak

tl;dr is at the bottom for those not wanting reasons, just questions.

I have the latest TeamSpeak client downloaded from the site of the authors of said program. I've managed, after a load of fiddling then some searching, that a .run file is stupidly packaged and needs modifying to be an executable instead, so I did that and ran the bleeding thing. It gave me a folder full of useless twiddle and files that were named as if they were thought up by a hyper-active, Star Trek addicted seven year old doped up on a recent 10 season marathon and various amphetamines.

I got a bit frustrated at the lack of working files and then went online where I noticed people were just telling others to run a file called "ts3client_linux_x86". That's swell, and all, but that file just flashes a terminal on my screen for less than a second. So I set about trying to capture it on a print-screen to as to actually read what it's saying.

After about 5 or 6 minutes of trying, I finally managed to immortalise Bigfoot's purple and white box of a brother, only to find out that kid's back at it again, and this time he's got his phasers set to acronym. In the picture is the message:

"This application failed to start because it could not find or load the Qt platform plugin "xcb".

Available platform plugins are: xcb.

Reinstalling the application may fix this problem."

Now, I've never installed a Qt or a xcb and never intended to, as I've never heard of them before, so I assumed it was telling me to reinstall the TS client .run thing again. I got the same message every single time I did it, so now I was lead to believe it wants one of these plugin things. "Off to google!" I shouted, it blissful, blissful ignorance. My adventure was far from blissful.

I've stumbled into the cave of monsters that seem really really fond on talking a language only they know - they also seem to enjoy building doors into their cave in some vehement attempt to be as open as possible while becoming more confusing than discerning why Suarez has the munchies.

They all spoke gibberish. Every single thread I found. Nothing helped and no one seemed to be getting the idea that what they were on about is useless to the people asking them questions. When a kid asks you what life means, you tell them something simple like "having fun" or "making your mark on the world"; you don't tell them it's an existential crisis that mankind has faced for eons as the answer is entirely subjective, then leave them wondering what "exissensul cry sis" means - the rest of your drivel long forgotten.

---

tl;dr, what body part of this OS do I need to suck to get something working? What's xcb and qt and where do I get some? Can anyone speak in a language that's universal, or will I need to look up google translate Linux > English?

I'm on 12.04. It's dual boot, my main being Win7. I want TS3 not TS2 (TS2's on the software centre).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Qt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Qt_%28software%29) is a framework for making apps. [XCB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xcb) is a library for playing with X11. (These links probably won't tell you much :P) You should have XCB already installed. Qt may be not installed, but TeamSpeak should either install it or bring his own copy with itself.

When googling, I found few possible solutions, but you would need some Linux knowledge to try them out. I recommend that you start a thread at [their forum](http://forum.teamspeak.com) and ask for help. Either you broke your system (not likely) or TeamSpeak is faulty (likely). If it's their fault, they should fix it.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, dude, will do. I would have asked on their forums first, but the XCB and Qt things made it seem like I'd have more chance with a question posed to these forums instead.

As a side note, I would upvote your comment, but apparently I need 15 rep, sorry.

Comment: @user298958 You can just mark it as accepted answer instead. Well, theoretically your system may be broken, but newbies usually don't break their systems randomly and Ubuntu 12.04 is a popular distro, so it would be weird if it wasn't supported.